# Anaconda installation not working in Chromebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, chromebook

I recently bought a chromebook. I tried installing Anaconda in the linux terminal. After installation I even ran `source ~/ .bash-rc`. But I am not able to open any conda related applications( I just need Jupiter NBs). I am getting the following error if I use any conda cmd `-bash: conda: command not found`.

I haven't activated developer mode. Please help me out.

Comment: This is the first result on google search. Did you try this ?- https://wsvincent.com/install-python3-chromebook/

Answer (score 0):

I've not installed anaconda on ChromeOS, but have had some luck with [pip and virtual environments](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/). Focusing on the OP's remark "I just need Jupiter[sic] NBs," the following worked for me today on my Samsung Chromebook Pro purchased circa early 2018 without developer mode enabled:

- Install [Termux](https://termux.com/) from Google Play.  I had to uninstall and reinstall Termux to get around an old dependency mess.
- Install Firefox or another non-Chrome Android browser from Google Play.  Android apps, like Termux, run a separate sandbox from Chrome and can be difficult to access.  You might be able to point Chrome at Android's private IP address (available from `ifconfig`, e.g. http://100.115.92.2:8888), but that didn't work for me today.
- From Termux, enter the commands from [gatopeich's gist](https://gist.github.com/gatopeich/8debf57e4fd8188f2f6610c6f5b0cf55)

```
    pkg upgrade
    pkg install python python-dev libzmq-dev libcrypt-dev clang
    pip3 install -U pip
    pip3 install pyzmq --install-option="--zmq=/usr/lib"
    pip3 install jupyter
```

- From Termux, run `jupyter-notebook`
- Point Firefox (or other Android non-Chrome browser) at the URL printed in the output from `jupyter-notebook`